# UITableViewCell as subview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I want to reuse views and code

Is it ok to add a UITableViewCell as a subview to a common view and not in UITableView?

Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea. `UITableViewCell` is made to serve as a cell and nothing else. Just like `UIButton` is made to be a clickable button. But you might think "well the button looks good, shouldn't i reuse it just as a subview?". No, you shouldn't do that. Button is a button, cell is a cell and so on. If you want to reuse your code then you should provide a kind of custom `UIView` and let it be subview for your cell or anything you want